# Realizar sub-consulta com dados de uma primeira

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá amigos eis que surgiu uma dúvida, onde mesmo entrando em vários fóruns não obtive exito em sana-la, desta forma vejam se conseguem me dar uma "luz".
Possuo um SELECT principal, e algumas sub-consultas. Em uma destas sub-consultas necessito passar como parâmetro na cláusula WHERE uma coluna que esta presente no SELECT principal, algo parecido o que há abaixo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID AS NUMERO_CONTRATO,
        QUANTIDADE   = (SELECT COUNT(PARCELA) FROM 
        CONTRATO_FINANCEIRO WHERE ID = NUMERO_CONTRATO)
FROM  CONTRATO_FINANCEIRO
```

Contudo após executar esta consulta é gerado erro pois não existe o campo NUMERO_CONTRATO, e caso eu passe a própria coluna ID ela por sua vez não irá com o valor da primeira consulta.

Comment: Já tentou usar JOIN?

Comment: Pensou eu que não irá necessitar de JOIN, para funcionar a consulta basta unicamente que a coluna (NUMERO_CONTRATO) que eu passo como parâmetro na clausula WHERE da sub-consulta seja "aceita"

Comment: @JuniorFerreiraDoNascimento: Faltou relacionar a subconsulta com a consulta. A isto se denomina subconsulta correlacionada. //  Avaliou a proposta do Rovann? Me parece a solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O trecho `QUANTIDADE = (subselect)` está errado. E Basta você atribuir um nome à tabela em que você está dando os `SELECT`. Para sua necessidade, o código ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.ID AS NUMERO_CONTRATO,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(b.PARCELA) 
     FROM CONTRATO_FINANCEIRO b 
     WHERE b.ID = a.id) as QUANTIDADE
FROM CONTRATO_FINANCEIRO a
```

ou, simplesmente você pode fazer assim, já que está tudo na mesma tabela:

```
SELECT 
    ID AS NUMERO_CONTRATO,
    COUNT(PARCELA) as QUANTIDADE 
FROM CONTRATO_FINANCEIRO
GROUP BY ID
```